# Facebook bulk request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question regarding facebook graph api. I have database of users' facebook IDs. My application retrieves information about users' events according to that field from facebook.

Application connects to Facebook, checks is user with specisic `facebook_id` has events. If there are found events it (app) retrieves info about specific event. So, it does lots of requests and scrips executes for very long time. I don't like this.

Does anybody know way to reduce number of requests so that I could check wich users have aliable events using one request and get detailed info about each of them using another?

I believe Facebook must have such ability. Link to facebook graph api documentation or to any answer on SO would be enough.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:** I've found the solution. Who can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), Luke!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the
>   "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL
>   https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in
>   the same response.

Not sure how many ids can be specified at once - not many I guess, as urls have a max length.

Alternatively, subscribe to [real time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) from Facebook to watch for event changes for each user id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. That is good. I saw it in the documentation. Now my app breaks the server if nearly 100 request are made. I don't think that GET-var `ids` allows to specify  as many ids as I wish. So this problem will appear again once number of requests is increased. I'll check real time updates.